# ZipPackage interaction with a shortcut

Tags: c#, file-io, zip, shortcut

I have a folder structure containing a number of documents, as well as a shortcut link to another file in the folder structure.  (essentially the file structure maps like a graph).  If I zip up these files in Windows, the shortcut will point to the right file when the archive is uncompressed somewhere else.

Now, I want to be able to do this using the [System.IO.Packaging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.zippackage.aspx) stuff... this requires that I put the each file in a stream to tie it to the zip file.  The problem is shortcut files (.lnk) apparently aren't actually files (if you do a file.exist on it, its not there).  My normal method of...

```
System.IO.FileStream(shortcut, System.IO.FileMode.Open)
```

...will not work.  So how would I add a shortcut to a zip package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `ZipPackage` isn't a regular Zip file, but a file meant to be used by new Office XML-based file format (docx, xlsx, etc).

If you want to zip something, you should to use another library, like [`#ziplib`](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/)